# New to baking having trouble understanding artifacts

Tags: texture-baking

I'm trying to unserstand what is the issue with my model thats generating Oclusion where it shouldn't or weird Normal Map in some places.

Like here: It produced a shadow in the low poly version:
[image: Theres no overlapping faces of vertices]

[image: The High poly version also seems clean, with no overlapping faces or vertices.]

[image: weird normal mapping]

.blend file with everything i've baked packed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pDOnffdYL0gIzlhBSWsv8h_ywJJIcg5W/view?usp=sharing

Update: this might be a blender issue. I baked with Substance Painter and there was no issues with my model

Comment: we can't download, it needs a password, please use another platform  ;)

Comment: Forgot to set the link as public. You can download it now.